# Migrate base R plot to ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is a 10-column excerpt from a 25k-column dataset:

```
bnc7log_t <- structure(c(3.8073549220576, 17.0416377642775, 14.1180488428888, 
                         10.5507467853832, 9.01959072835788, 15.3172006034227, 0, 6.85798099512757, 
                         17.3531640594242, 14.2536997813742, 1, 13.9409558756115, 13.8783383498952, 
                         11.5783726913608, 6.85798099512757, 15.013933264159, 14.1180488428888, 
                         16.2415363334906, 14.4605198895249, 16.2071287425943, 6.52356195605701, 
                         6.85798099512757, 17.0416377642775, 12.0864679934641, 10.1786648510065, 
                         14.1270270430046, 17.0416377642775, 14.2651022184843, 16.2071287425943, 
                         16.2071287425943, 3.16992500144231, 0, 16.2071287425943, 1.58496250072116, 
                         8.24317398347295, 16.2071287425943, 16.2071287425943, 10.8470573460913, 
                         3.90689059560852, 14.4809794856131, 12.111787735801, 10.4325419003883, 
                         16.2071287425943, 16.2071287425943, 6.39231742277876, 15.3172006034227, 
                         5.95419631038687, 15.3426997374694, 15.8411957647929, 16.2071287425943, 
                         9.18487534290828, 15.101770541626, 16.9654686605993, 10.5449644327892, 
                         11.7780771295354, 10.4429434958487, 16.2071287425943, 9.63662462054365, 
                         14.1249290466025, 16.4715482109991, 15.2312961941021, 16.4566110995749, 
                         15.950419202689, 16.2071287425943, 1, 2.8073549220576, 5.70043971814109, 
                         12.5636729598275, 3.58496250072116, 3), .Dim = c(7L, 10L), .Dimnames = list(
                           c("f1log", "f2log", "f3log", "f4log", "f5log", "f6log", "f7log"
                           ), NULL))
```

I'm plotting the data in `base R` but the execution takes ages, probably due to the `for` loop:

```
plot(bnc7log_t[,1],
     main = paste0("Within-turn corpus frequencies in 7-word turns\n(N = ", ncol(bnc7log_t), " turns)"), 
     cex.main = 0.9, cex.axis = 0.9, cex.lab = 0.9,
     ylab = "Within-turn frequencies (log2)",
     xlab = "Turn positions",
     ylim = c(0,18),
     type = "n", col = "grey", frame = F,
     xaxt = "n")
axis(1, at = 1:7, labels = paste0("w", 1:7), cex.axis = 0.8)
grid(nx = 10)

for(i in 1:ncol(bnc7log_t)){
  lines(jitter(bnc7log_t[,i], factor = 2), 
        type = "l"
        )
}
```

I'm sure execution is speedier in `ggplot2` - just how can it the plot be migrated to `ggplot2`?

Comment: How many rows has the full data set, can you post `dim(bnc7log_t)`?

Comment: The full data set has just 7 rows but 25830 columns. This is the result of a `t`ranspose operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two solutions, one of them a base R solution though it is not asked for. The reason why this is because many times forgotten function `matplot` might do the job more quickly than the `for` loop in the question.

```r
bnc7log_t <- structure(
  c(3.8073549220576, 17.0416377642775, 14.1180488428888, 
    10.5507467853832, 9.01959072835788, 15.3172006034227, 0, 6.85798099512757, 
    17.3531640594242, 14.2536997813742, 1, 13.9409558756115, 13.8783383498952, 
    11.5783726913608, 6.85798099512757, 15.013933264159, 14.1180488428888, 
    16.2415363334906, 14.4605198895249, 16.2071287425943, 6.52356195605701, 
    6.85798099512757, 17.0416377642775, 12.0864679934641, 10.1786648510065, 
    14.1270270430046, 17.0416377642775, 14.2651022184843, 16.2071287425943, 
    16.2071287425943, 3.16992500144231, 0, 16.2071287425943, 1.58496250072116, 
    8.24317398347295, 16.2071287425943, 16.2071287425943, 10.8470573460913, 
    3.90689059560852, 14.4809794856131, 12.111787735801, 10.4325419003883, 
    16.2071287425943, 16.2071287425943, 6.39231742277876, 15.3172006034227, 
    5.95419631038687, 15.3426997374694, 15.8411957647929, 16.2071287425943, 
    9.18487534290828, 15.101770541626, 16.9654686605993, 10.5449644327892, 
    11.7780771295354, 10.4429434958487, 16.2071287425943, 9.63662462054365, 
    14.1249290466025, 16.4715482109991, 15.2312961941021, 16.4566110995749, 
    15.950419202689, 16.2071287425943, 1, 2.8073549220576, 5.70043971814109, 
    12.5636729598275, 3.58496250072116, 3), 
  .Dim = c(7L, 10L), 
  .Dimnames = list(
    c("f1log", "f2log", "f3log", "f4log", "f5log", "f6log", "f7log"), 
    NULL))

suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(tidyr)
  library(ggplot2)
})



matplot(
  bnc7log_t, type = "l", lty = "solid", col = "grey",
  main = paste0("Within-turn corpus frequencies in 7-word turns\n(N = ", ncol(bnc7log_t), " turns)"), 
  cex.main = 0.9, cex.axis = 0.9, cex.lab = 0.9,
  ylab = "Within-turn frequencies (log2)",
  xlab = "Turn positions"
)
```

[image]

```r
bnc7log_t %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column("x") %>% 
  mutate(x = as.integer(x)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, value, group = name)) +
  geom_line(colour = "grey", alpha = 0.5) + 
  labs(x = "Turn positions", y = "Within-turn frequencies (log2)") +
  ggtitle(paste0("Within-turn corpus frequencies in 7-word turns\n(N = ", ncol(bnc7log_t), " turns)")) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Is this close to what you want?

```
library(tidyverse)

as_tibble(bnc7log_t) %>% 
  mutate(Row=1:7) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    starts_with("V"),
    values_to="Value",
    names_to="Column"
  ) %>% 
  ggplot() +
    geom_line(aes(x=Row, y=Value, group=Column)) +
    labs(
      x="Turn positions", 
      y="Within-turn frequencies (log2)",
      title=paste0("Within-turn corpus frequencies in 7-word turns\n(N = ", ncol(bnc7log_t), " turns)")
    ) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=1:7, labels=paste0("w", 1:7))
```

[image]

Comment: Pretty close. How can I increase the alpha value? In `base R`this would be done by `col = rgb(0, 0, 0, 05, maxColorValue = 250)`

Comment: The alpha value of what?  The background? (Sorry, I'm not familiar with base R graphics.)  If so, then `+ theme_light()` will get you pretty close.  An exact match should be possible with a little tweaking.

Comment: No I meant the alpah value of the plotting color, which is black. I need it to plot with high transparency

Comment: Ah!  In that case, @RuiBarradas has given you two options: either set the line colour with `colour=` or the transparency with `alpha=`.  Or both.  Make sure you add the options *outside* the call to `aes()` - if you don't you will generate legend entries that you will need to suppress.